# WPF DataGrid In TabItem unable to select rows

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have this nice little Window..

```
<Window x:Class="Kassa.OfficeMainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kassa"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Kontor" Height="720" Width="1280" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
    <TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
        <TabItem Header="Müük">
            <TabControl>
                <TabItem Header="Ülevaade"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Sooduskampaaniad"></TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Kliendid"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tootehaldus ja ladu" x:Name="ProductsTab">
            <DockPanel>
                <GroupBox Header="Otsi tootekoodi, triipkoodi või nime järgi, või lisa uus toode" Padding="0,4,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <Grid Height="22">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ProductSearchBox" KeyUp="ProductSearchBox_KeyUp" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Padding="8,0" Margin="8,0">Uus toode</Button>
                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Tulemuste filtreerimine ja lao operatsioonid" Padding="0,4,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="4,0" IsChecked="True" x:Name="CheckBoxAllProducts" Click="CheckBoxForProducts_Click">Kõik</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="4,0" x:Name="CheckBoxProductsInStock" Click="CheckBoxForProducts_Click">Laos</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="4,0" x:Name="CheckBoxProductsBelowCritical" Click="CheckBoxForProducts_Click">Allpool kriitilist kogust</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="4,0" x:Name="CheckBoxProductsOutOfStock" Click="CheckBoxForProducts_Click">Laost otsas</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="4,0" x:Name="CheckBoxNotInventoried"  Click="CheckBoxForProducts_Click">Laoseisu ei arvestata</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="4,0" x:Name="CheckBoxArchieved" Click="CheckBoxForProducts_Click">Arhiveeritud</CheckBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Button Padding="8,0"  Margin="8,0" Height="22">Lattu võtmine</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </GroupBox>
                <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="ProductDataGrid" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False"  CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" RowHeaderWidth="0">
                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCritical}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tootekood" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Code}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nimetus" Width="*"  Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Triipkood" Width="*"  Binding="{Binding Path=Barcode}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Laoseisuga" Binding="{Binding Path=HasInventory}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Laos ühikuid"  Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentStock}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTracked}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"></Setter>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kriitiline kogus"  Binding="{Binding Path=CriticalStock}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTracked}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"></Setter>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Omahind"  Binding="{Binding Path=SelfPrice}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="KM %"  Binding="{Binding Path=VATPercentage}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Müügihind" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=SellingPrice}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Staatus" Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DockPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

I want this DataGrid to have the resize and reorder features turned off, that I have, I want to not be able to edit the cells. BUT, and this is not working.. I want to be able to still select and highlight rows when I click on them. This for some reason does not work...

MVCE: Even row selection on this does not work

```
 <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="ProductDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nimetus" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vöötkood" Binding="{Binding Barcode}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Laoseisuga" Binding="{Binding HasInventory}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Laos ühikuid"  Binding="{Binding CurrentStock}">

                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kriitiline kogus"  Binding="{Binding CriticalStock}">

                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Omahind"  Binding="{Binding SelfPrice}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="KM %"  Binding="{Binding VATPercentage}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Müügihind" Binding="{Binding SellingPrice}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Staatus" Binding="{Binding Status}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: It works just fine for me. Could you please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without any event handlers and other unrelated stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what was wrong, the error was what I was doing in `<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">` SelectionChanged, was setting the datagrid contents. As it turns out, whenever you select a control in a tab, that event bubbles up to the TabControl, and therefore the row does not get selected.